# Codeigniter min price other data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can get the lowest value in my table. 
but I can't get the id number of the lowest price I found.
how can I do it?

```
$this->db->query = "select id, price from mytable where price = (select min(price) from mytable)";
$this->db->get('mytable');

For example:
ID      PRICE
1       249
2       229
3       339
4       449
```

I want to result: Id:2 Price:229

I can only get the price. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select_min('PRICE');
$this->db->limit(1); 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
result $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select one row (the one with the lowest price). There's several ways to do it both using and not using query builder.

The easiest one:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->order_by('price', 'asc');
$this->db->limit(1);

$result = $this->db->get();
```

Then return the data to your controller:

```
return $result->row(0);
```

and you'll have a nice object with all fields from the row with the lowest price